# Pagination.. add spans and increment number

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, pagination

I want to divide my array into pages, 4 per page. I have found out how many pages I will need:

```
var no_of_entries = docs.length;
var no_of_pages = (Math.round(no_of_entries / 4));
```

How would I add 's with page numbers in and a unique id from this variable?

i.e if the variable for no_of_pages is 3, I'll need 3 spans, numbered 1-3 each with unique id's (preferabbly the id matching the number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might try something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= no_of_pages; i++) {
  $('.YOUR-WRAPPER').append('<span id="ID-NAME' + i + '">Whatever text you want</span>')
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NqdBW/

Answer (score 0):

create an empty div in the markup with an ID. In your javascript (I assume that's what this is) create a loop using your no_of_pages as the upper limit. Simply add span tags markup to the div you created while inide the loop. The loop counter can give your span the page number label.